# For each hidden cell set a value in a cell in that hidden cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have a table(A3-6) that un-hides rows according to the number entered into a cell above the table(A1). In Row column A3-6 the user selects an option in the cell which has a list of data valadation. Now what I want to do is for each of the hidden cells set the values in the hidden cells to the default option.

```
Dim i As Long
        For i = 2 To 10
            If (Rows("2:10").Hidden = True) Then
                'Set the default values for the cell?
        End If
        Next i
```

This code hides the rows according to the number entered into A1

```
If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then
        Rows("3:6").Hidden = True
        Rows("2:" & 2 + Val(Target.Value)).Hidden = False
    End If
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "default" value ? Would a statement like `Cells(2,2) = "MyDefaultValue"` work ?

Comment: Well there is a small table about 5 cells long with values in each cell. I used that to create a data validation list and option 1 from the drop down is a default. In column B, the user can only select an option out of that list. Does that answer your question @d-stroyer?

Comment: Sorry for the long answer, but yes that will work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can possibly give you some ideas:

```
Sub resetHiddenRangeValue()

    Dim rngMyRange As Range, rngVisible As Range, rngCell As Range

    Set rngMyRange = Range("A3:A6")
    Set rngVisible = Range("A3:A6").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    For Each rngCell In rngMyRange
        If Intersect(rngCell, rngVisible) Is Nothing Then
            ' Is the default value rngcell.offset(0,6).value?
            rngCell.Value = "My Default Value" 
        End If
    Next rngCell

End Sub
```

It is possible to avoid looping, but its a bit trickier:

```
Sub resetHiddenRangeValueNoLooping()

    Dim rngMyRange As Range, rngVisible As Range, rngHidden As Range, varVisible As Variant

    Set rngMyRange = Range("A3:A6")
    Set rngVisible = Range("A3:A6").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    ' Trick: store the initial values of the visible range to a variant array
    varVisible = rngVisible.Value

    ' Substitute the contents of rngVisible with something random
    rngVisible.Value = "Blah_Blah_Blah"

    ' Use the Columndifferences method to set the hidden range
    Set rngHidden = rngMyRange.ColumnDifferences(rngVisible(1, 1))

    ' Fill up the range with the default value-can also be an array or range of values
    rngHidden.Value = "My Default Value"

    ' restore the original values of the visible range
    rngVisible.Value = varVisible

End Sub
```

Comment: Also I think  that in your first code segment, if you replace `(Rows("2:10").Hidden = True)` with `Cells(i,1).hidden = True` and then set `Cells(i,1) = "My Default Value"` it should work..

Comment: Yep, good one (but I was in the bathroom hence the delay :) )